# Grafana Geomap Location

Tags: python, prometheus, grafana

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNEOI.jpg)
as you can see, I have 2 values that I got from prometheus metrics "xml_file_count" and "sxml_file_count". These are counting the number of xml vs sxml files on the computer. But I want it to appear in my current position via geomap. For example, when the number of xml_file_count exceeds 10, let it position where I am with green, and if it is less than 10, let it be red. But I tried to do something from the place I squared off on the right, but it showed a different location, so even though I was in Europe, it marked Africa on the map. How can I solve this problem?

i tried the part I enclosed in red on the right side of the photo, but I don't know much because I'm a beginner

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.